# How to see all intentions in intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

In my code on the line ***//some describtion text*** I can make Intention "Replace with block comment". When I click **Analyze/Inspect code** I see inspections, but not intentions.

How does I can see all places in my module where I can make this Intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"intention" is a quick action list for your current selection.

so there is no perfect final stage for the intention.

For example, select one line comment, you can do "Replace with block comment", after it become block comment, you can do "Replace with end-of-line comments", and it will reverse back.

You can not find all intentions, list them out, and fix all, because intention is not an error.